# HAVING clause with a LEFT JOIN and sqlite

Tags: sqlite, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables, say T1 and T2, with a 1-n relationship (n can be 0). I need to join the 2 tables, but only on the latest T2. So the query I made was like:

```
select * from t1 left join t2 on t1.a = t2.b group by t1.a having t2.c=max(t2.c)
```

Problem is that if there a no lines on T2 the query does not return a line, despite the LEFT JOIN. I think this is incorrect in regards to the SQL standard.

So does anyone know how to have a result even when n=0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HAVING is executed *after* the grouping.
And any comparison with NULL fails, so this filters out rows with `n=0`.

In any case, `t2.c=max(t2.c)` does not make sense and does not do what you want.

If you have SQLite 3.7.11 or later, you can use `max()` in the result to select the row from which the GROUP BY results for the other columns come:

```
SELECT *, max(t2.c)
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.a = t2.b
GROUP BY t1.a
```

Comment: the having clause works with other DB and works with sqlite for    n>0    . Anyway your solution works so thanks a lot :)